# HTML- run in local - Cross Browser issue

Tags: python, html, node.js, cross-browser, localhost

I am trying to create code editor for python so  I copied code from original site. Facing issue when I try to run it like: “Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.”Eerror when loading a local file"

To solve this, I have got some solutions from stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

I am at startup stage I cant understand how they are fixed. But almost I did  fix it as per git answer but it did not work properly.

"ht t p s://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-thi n gs- locally"

The following image is what I got from.!!

[image: This is what i got]

The below image is what I got from the browser.!!

[image: browser image]

Can anyone help me to fix it? Kindly share your knowledge/idea/any other solution/ working code etc.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Access Allow Origin` ? You can't send same header on different requests !

Comment: @dsgdfg  "Access Allow Origin " what is this about.? can't understand. then as per you view how to fix it. here "same header" means what?